# Using DRAKON with python's try: except: exceptions

Tags: python, drakon, drakon-editor

Is anyone familiar with DRAKON?

I quite like the idea of the DRAKON visual editor and have been playing with it using Python -- more info: http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/python/python.html

The only thing I've had a problem with so far is python's try: except: exceptions. The only way I've attempted it is to use branches and then define try: and except: as separate actions below the branch. The only thing with this is that DRAKON doesn't pick up the try: and automatically indent the exception code afterwards.

Is there any way to handle try: except: in a visual way in DRAKON, or perhaps you've heard of another similar visual editor project for python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the whole "try: except:" construct inside one "Action" icon like this:

[image: Catching exceptions in DRAKON-Python]

Both spaces and tabs can be used for indentation inside an icon.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I did first of all, but then when try: and except: has various loops and such, it more or less defeats the purpose of this kind of visual editor.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitation exist in Drakon since it is a code generator, but what you can do is to re-factor the code as much as possible and stuff it inside action block:

```
try:
   function_1()
   function_2()
except:
   function_3()
```

Drakon works best if you follow suggested rules(skewer,happy route,branching etc).

Once you construct algorithm base on this, it can help you solve complex problems fast.

Hope thats help.